# how do I set windows form in c# to accept null vales in textbox and combobox

Tags: c#

There are six rows in my windows form c# but some times I want to hide a couple of row , I know how to set textBox or combox visibility to false but then when the code executes I get "“Input string was not in a correct format”" error on one of the lines mentioned below, how do I set these to accept null vales ? Please help I have been stuck for days now.

```
        gpa.semester = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject = textBox1.Text;
        gpa.credithours = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
        gpa.marks = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
gpaform4 gpa = new gpaform4();

```
        gpa.semester = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject = textBox1.Text;
        gpa.credithours = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
        gpa.marks = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);





        //gpa.semester1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject1 = textBox3.Text;
        gpa.credithours1 = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);
        gpa.marks1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);


        //gpa.semester2 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject2 = textBox4.Text;
        gpa.credithours2 = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox4.Text);
        gpa.marks2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);

        //gpa.semester3 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject3 = textBox5.Text;
        gpa.credithours3 = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox5.Text);
        gpa.marks3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text);

        //gpa.semester4 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject4 = textBox6.Text;
        gpa.credithours4 = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox6.Text);
        gpa.marks4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text);

        //gpa.semester5 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        gpa.subject5 = textBox7.Text;
        gpa.credithours5 = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox7.Text);
        gpa.marks5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text);

        BLL tbll = new BLL();
       

        bool b = tbll.Gpafrom4Bll(gpa);
        if (b)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GPA Calculated");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GPA not Calculated");
        }
        Row1();
        Row2();
        Row3();
        Row4();
        Row5();
        Row6();

        textBox13.Text = total_credithours.ToString();  
        textBox14.Text = totalgragepoints.ToString();  
        textBox15.Text = ((totalgragepoints / total_credithours).ToString());

        gpa sgpa = new gpa();
        sgpa.semester = comboBox1.Text;
        double testgpa = totalgragepoints / total_credithours;
        sgpa.semestergpa = testgpa.ToString();


        BLL tbll1 = new BLL();
        tbll1.SgpaBll(sgpa);

    }
```

Comment: comboBox2.Text??string.Empty, if (int.TryParse(textBox12.Text, out val)){}

Comment: `on one of the lines mentioned below, ` Which one?

Comment: What do you want `Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);` to return when the combo box is null / empty?

Comment: I want textbox and combobox in a windows form to accept null values, right now when I execute the code and try to enter the data it gives me “Input string was not in a correct format” error because there is no value in the textbox or combo box.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsM4Z.png

Comment: Never create your own grid control scheme, use DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the TextBox value is null or empty (String.IsNullOrEmpty) before attempting to use the value, or use `Int32.TryParse` instead.

If you choose to use `Convert.ToInt32` you should use exception handling (try-catch).

Comment: This is the right "answer", but it's really more of a comment than an answer